# Can't search the app with originial name in the AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-search, app-store-optimization

We have a published app in Apple App Store, but when we search the app we can only find it through related words. Let's assume the name is **NoFake-Be real**, we can see the app in related words after typing in **NoFa** however can't search it if we put in **NoFake**.

What could be the reasons?  And what can we do to enable the app can be searched with its original name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, Apple search will not find your app by name from the first couple of days, then after that your app will be usually searchable by its name.

Also, You can add the name of the app to the `key words` from app store connect, Also you can add different localization to enhance the result.